# how to specify HTML for each dataGridView row item using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, webbrowser-control

I currently use a string builder and various loops to parse some HTML to a webBrowser control. But how can i specific each column and value from my `dataGridView1` so that i can wrap HTML around. I have a column with a row value in my dataGridView1 which is an image URL.

```
private StringBuilder htmlMessageBody(DataGridView dataGridView2)
{
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    //create html & table
    strB.AppendLine("<html><body><center><" +
                    "table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    //cteate table header
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" +
                        dataGridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>");
    }
    //create table body
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
        foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells)
        {
            strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" +
                            dgvc.Value.ToString() + "</td>");
        }
        strB.AppendLine("</tr>");

    }
    //table footer & end of html file
    strB.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
    return strB;


}
```

Comment: Your code misplaces some <TR> tags and misses the </TR> tag for the first occurence of <TR>. Anyway, i don't know if this is related to your problem, which i unfortunately don't understand.

Comment: In simple terms how do i display a row from my dataGridView

Comment: I just edited/updated my comment. If the problems are related about rows, then it smells like it being related to the errors with the <TR> tags...

Answer (score 0):

```
 //create table body
strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
```

I think this needs to be

```
 //create table body
strB.AppendLine("</tr>");
```

to close the row tag before you start forlooping more table rows.

If you put a breakpoint on your return statement you can copy the contents of StrB into a html editor which should highlight your errors.